# How to get EntityFramework to save my instances without inserting duplicate records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a model that looks like this:

```
public class WorkflowDefinition
{
    public List<WorkflowStepRelationship> Relationships { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public WorkflowStepDefinition StartingStepDefinition { get; private set; }
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
}

public class WorkflowStepRelationship
{
    public WorkflowStepDefinition InitialStep { get; private set; }
    public List<WorkflowStepDefinition> NextSteps { get; private set; }
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
}

public class WorkflowStepDefinition
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
}
```

The idea being that a workflow consists of a starting step and a collection of relationships that allow you to navigate from that starting step to the collection of next available steps. So by definition the `StartingStepDefinition` in the `WorkflowDefinition` will also be the `InitialStep` in one of the `Relationships` in the `WorkflowDefinition`.

I am using code first to generate the database.

The problem is when I try and save a `WorkflowDefinition` which has this setup I get an error saying that it can't insert a duplicate row in the `WorkflowStepDefinitions` table, and it seems to be trying to insert the `StartingStepDefinition` and then another `WorkflowStepDefinition` with the same ID when it tries to save the associated `WorkflowStepRelationship`

How can I tell the EF that the `WorkflowStepDefinition` in the `InitialStep` of the `WorkflowStepRelationship` is the same instance as the `StartingStepDefinition` in the `WorkflowDefinition` and to not try and create a new instance when it is saving the `WorkflowDefinition`?

Comment: Sounds like you need to define a primary key on the `WorkflowStepDefinition` and a foreign key relationship from the `WorkflowStepRelationship` to the `WorkflosStepDefinition`.  Unfortunately, I haven't worked with code first so I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @TonyVitabile The Id columns are generated as primary keys and the navigation properties (the properties that are other model types or lists of other model types mean that foreign key relationships are generated.  The database model seems ok (well adequate), its just that the framework is trying to save the same entities twice, rather than saving it once and seeing that it is trying to save an entity which has already been saved when it encounters it again in the object graph.

Comment: @SamHolder It sounds like you have `1:N` relation here. If I get it right each workflow has exactly one `InitialStep` but the same `InitialStep` can be used for multiple workflows. Maybe this can be solved on `EF` side but I think that it's a good place to use another table for the `InitialSteps`

Comment: @Leron Correct that a workflow has exactly one InitialStep, but that initial step is just a WorkflowStepDefinition, and the WorkflowStepDefinitions have their own table. But the EF inserts a record into this table for the InitialStep and then tries to insert an identical record for the WorkflowStepDefinition it finds in the InitialStep of the WorkflowStepRelationship, which has the same Id, and .Equals() returns true for instances with the same id.